# Underscore.js - Looping through Object Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, underscore.js

I have the following object array:

```
var products = [
    {
        id: 1,
        name: "Product 1",
        subTypes: [
            {
                id: 1,
                name: "Product 1 - Sub Type 1"
            },
            {
                id: 2,
                name: "Product 1 - Sub Type 2"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        name: "Product 2",
        subTypes: [
            {
                id: 1,
                name: "Product 2 - Sub Type 1"
            },
            {
                id: 2,
                name: "Product 2 - Sub Type 2"
            }
        ]
    }
];
```

Using underscore.js why does the following dot notation not log anything to console:

```
_.each(products.subTypes, function(subType) {
       console.log(subType.name);
 });
```

I can only get it to work by doing nesting the foreach loops as follows?

```
_.each(products, function (product) {
    _.each(product.subTypes, function (subType) {
        console.log(subType.name);
    });
});
```

Comment: There is no products.subTypes infact you need something like products[0].subTypes and products[1].subTypes and so on

Comment: Your last piece of code above is exactly the correct assumption. You have an array of objects as a property within an array of objects - you'll need to loop twice. You can't access it with `products.subTypes` as this it trying to access the property of a single object.

Answer (score 0):

You can check it

```
console.log('Subtypes:', products.subTypes.name);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to access product.subTypes you have to extract them from your objects first.

Here is how you do it. 3 example functions: pure javascript, ES6, underscoreJS.

```js
// pure JS
function pureJsloop(data) {
  var result = [];

  for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    var product = data[i];
    
    result.push(product.subTypes);

  }
  
  return result[0];
}

// ES6
function ES6loop(data) {
  // We are returning reduced array
  return data.reduce((previous, product) => {
    return previous = [ ...previous, product.subTypes ];
  }, [])[0];
}

// Underscore
function underscoreLoop(data) {

  return _.reduce(data, function(previous, product){ 
    return previous = [ ...previous, product.subTypes ];
  }, [])[0];
  
}


var products = [
              {
                id: 1,
                name: "Product 1",
                subTypes: [
                  {
                    id: 1,
                    name: "Product 1 - Sub Type 1"
                  },
                  {
                    id: 2,
                    name: "Product 1 - Sub Type 2"
                  }
                ]
              },
              {
                id: 2,
                name: "Product 2",
                subTypes: [
                  {
                    id: 1,
                    name: "Product 2 - Sub Type 1"
                  },
                  {
                    id: 2,
                    name: "Product 2 - Sub Type 2"
                  }
                ]
              }];
              


//console.log(pureJsloop(products));
//console.log(ES6loop(products));
console.log(underscoreLoop(products));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.8.3/underscore-min.js"></script>
```